# List of the same type as my trait, but only with the implementations

Tags: scala, list, traits

Let's say I have a simple trait called Constraint:

```
trait Constraint {

  def description: String

  def constraintValue: Int

  def applyConstraint
}
```

... and two classes that extend this trait:

```
class ConstraintA(val constraintValue: Int) extends Constraint {

  override def description: String = "CONSTRAINT_A"

  override def applyConstraint: Unit = {
    // ...
  }
}

class ConstraintB(val constraintValue: Int) extends Constraint {

  override def description: String = "CONSTRAINT_B"

  override def applyConstraint: Unit = {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I'm reading an XML file and instantiating a list of ConstraintA and Constraint B (the concrete implementations).

This is the code I use to read the file and create the list:

```
val xml = XML.loadFile(xmlFilePath)

val readConstraints = (xml \ "constraints") (0).attributes.map {
   c =>
     c.key match {
       case "CONSTRAINT_A" => new ConstraintA(c.value.text.toInt)
       case "CONSTRAINT_B" => new ConstraintB(c.value.text.toInt)
       case _ => Nil
     }
 }
```

The problem is that I want to return `List[Constraint]` but I get the error message: **Expression of type List[Object] doesn't conform to expected type List[Constraint]**.

Any hint on why the language does not infer the type?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code that returns the error in question.

Comment: Not clear how to reproduce that error.

Comment: Sure! Updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is you are returning two different types in case you need to return same if you want compiler to infer the type of your operation.

```
case "CONSTRAINT_A" => new ConstraintA(c.value.text.toInt)
case "CONSTRAINT_B" => new ConstraintB(c.value.text.toInt)
case _ => Nil
```

In the last case you are returning the Nil which is List of nothing.

And in the case CONSTRAINT_A you are returning CONSTRAINT_A  and so as in the case CONSTRAINT_B.  that is the reason the compiler is treating it as a list of objects.

Comment: Oh, that was it! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `match` expression can return `Constraint` or `Nil`, and the only common subtype is `Any` so the resulting type is `Any`. Thus the `map` operation returns `List[Any]`.

The fix is to remove the `case _` from the match expression.

Mark `Constraint` as `sealed` to avoid complaints from the compiler